# Google Maps API: Adding streetview to map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SULSV/

I use the following code to display a map on my website:

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="myMap" style="height:350px;width:680px"></div>
<input id="address" type="text" style="width:600px;"/>
<input type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>
```

**My JS:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;
var marker;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792, 85.84099235520011);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatlng,
        draggable: true
    });

    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': myLatlng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': marker.getPosition()
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
        });
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

My question: What code do I need to add in order to add a street view box under the map which is linked to the roadmap and shows the current position of the marker?

I alerady know that it is possible to initialize streetview by

```
new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("DIV-BOX"));
```

but I have no clue how to integrate streetview into my code.

Comment: this question was asked like 2 days ago. Do a search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define it via the `streetView`-property of the map:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetView: new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("DIV-BOX"))
};
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/SULSV/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/SULSV/1/)